# Cannot POST error using Express, Mongoose, EJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

(For the solution check the last answer)
I'm creating object with rating system with default value of 0. What I'm trying to do is to update the rating value by choosing one of the options in the `<select>` dropdown menu. The problem is when I'm submiting the selected value it sends the 'Cannot POST / ...' error.

Here's the app.js code with post and get requests:

```js
// Updating Single Object
app.post('project/:projectId', (req, res) => {
  const project = {};
  project.rating = req.body.rating;

  Project.update({_id: request.params.projectId}, project, (err) =>{
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      return;
    } else {
      res.redirect('/project/:projectId');
    }
  });
});

// Route To Single Project
app.get('/project/:projectId', (req, res) => {
  const requestedProjectId = req.params.projectId;
  Project.findOne({_id: requestedProjectId}).populate('image_file').exec((err, project) => {
    res.render('project', {
      project: project
    });
  });
});
```

And the form:

```html
<form action="/project/<%= project.id %>" method="post">
 <select class="" name="rating">
  <option value="0">Rate us</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```

I think I'm missing something but can't figure it out.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your url in routes, use  `/project/:projectId` instead of `project/:projectId` in `app.post()` method

Answer (score 1):

Solved it after 3 hours, realizing I was missing the `/` before `project` in the url route.

```js
app.post('project/:projectId', (req, res) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of:

```
<form action="/project/<%= project.id %>" method="post">
```

you should use:

```
<form action="/project/<%= project._id %>" method="post">
```

Comment: Unfortunately the problem still stays the same.